# How can a webcam be recognized by the kernel, but not found by uvcvideo?

Tags: webcam

I've got a Creative VF0640 webcam, which originally worked on an older Linux system, but is not working on an OpenSuSE Leap 15.1 (x86_64) machine. The kernel seems to recognize the cam when attaching it, but uvcvideo says there are no devices present:

```sh
╭─jacek@epica ~  
╰─➤  dmesg | tail
[ 3133.811825] usb 5-4: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 4467.063022] usb 5-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 4471.423219] usb 5-2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 4471.581496] usb 5-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0ac8, idProduct=3420
[ 4471.581500] usb 5-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 4471.581501] usb 5-2: Product: Vimicro USB 2.0 PC Camera (Venus)
[ 4471.581502] usb 5-2: Manufacturer: Vimicro
[ 4471.583898] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Vimicro USB 2.0 PC Camera (Venus) (0ac8:3420)
[ 4471.583902] uvcvideo: No streaming interface found for terminal 3.
[ 4471.583943] input: Vimicro USB 2.0 PC Camera (Venu as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0a:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.0/input/input14
╭─jacek@epica ~  
╰─➤  uvcdynctrl -lv     
Listing available devices:
No devices found.
```

Needless to say that none of my fron-end apps (guvcview-qt5 and kamoso) can't find the cam. I don't even find a device file:

```sh
╭─jacek@epica ~  
╰─➤  ls -al /dev/vid*
zsh: no matches found: /dev/vid*
```

This is my kernel version:

```
╭─jacek@epica ~  
╰─➤  uname -a                                                               1 ↵
Linux epica 4.12.14-lp151.28.36-default #1 SMP Fri Dec 6 13:50:27 UTC 2019 (8f4a495) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What's wrong here? Thank you.